# access class object data sent from client to server over socket

Tags: python, sockets

I have both a server and a client, I’m trying to send a class object over socket from client to server, the class object contains a list with 2 usernames and a variable with the length of list 2, in server I can successfully access the ctotalusers which gives me 2, but the userslist gives me [] why the users are missing ?

**client**

```
import socket, pickle, json

def create_send_users(i, y, k):
    msg = {'i': i, 'users': y, 'k': k}
    return json.dumps(msg)


class CaUsers(object):
    ctotalusers = None 
    userslist = []


users = CaUsers()
users.userslist.append("bob")
users.userslist.append("alice")
users.ctotalusers = len(users.userslist)


a_users = pickle.dumps(users)

msg = create_send_users("i", a_users, "k")

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 7038))
s.send(msg)
```

**server**

```
import socket, pickle, json, sys


class CaUsers(object):
    ctotalusers = None 
    userslist = []



HOST = '127.0.0.1'  
PORT = 7038

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('# Socket created')

# Create socket on port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print('# Bind failed. ')
    sys.exit()

print('# Socket bind complete')

# Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print('# Socket now listening')

# Wait for client
conn, addr = s.accept()
print('# Connected to ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))

# Receive data from client
while True:     
    data = conn.recv(4096)
    if data:
        users =  pickle.loads(json.loads(data)["users"])
        print users.ctotalusers # correct gives me 2 
        print users.userslist # wrong gives me []


s.close()
```

Comment: Why do you pickle the users? Usually when smth like this happens, do one step at a time, not more (`pickle.loads(json.loads(...`) and for each of them verify that everything is correct (strings length and so on). That at both ends! I have a feeling that it could be the fact that *pickle* yields a binary string, while *json* strings can't handle all chars (as *pickle* formats them).

Comment: can you provide an example ?

Comment: Oh, stupid me, I didn't notice that you just initialize some class variables, instead having an initializer (`__init__`).